# Oracle regexp_like negating special char

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g, caret, negate

I'm using Oracle 10g trying to EXCLUDE entries that contain a `-` or a `_` with a caret in the character class in Oracle 10g.  I can find the entries containing dash or underscore through:

```
WITH example
     AS (SELECT 'AAAA-1' n FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AAAAA_1' FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AAAA' FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM example
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (n, '[_\-]')
```

I know I can get by with using NOT but how do I negate this with a caret `(^)`?  I've tried `[^_\-]` which returns everything,  `[^[_\-]]` which returns nothing, and `[^(_\-)]` which is invalid.

Comment: You might find http://www.regexper.com/ useful for trying out the answers. It gives you a visual representation of the regex and has saved me hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH example
     AS (SELECT 'AAAA-1' n FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AAAAA_1' FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AAAA' FROM DUAL
         UNION
         SELECT 'AAAA\1' FROM DUAL
         )
SELECT *
  FROM example
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (n, '^[^_-]*$')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11093)

Comment: Cool, that works. Why do the anchors make this work? and why is the * necessary?  Thanks

Comment: @user2379830 - Look at femtoRgon's answer (about `*` and anchors).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^[^_-]*$
```

I believe that `[^_-]` matches anything, because it is looking for *Any* character that is anything other than '_' or '-'.  Similar to the opposite that works, `[_-]`, which finds any character, anywhere in the string, that *is* either a '-' or '_'.

To change that, accept any number of character matching you character class `[^_-]`, and surround with `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line).

Comment: This is incorrect.  Test it on a string containing backslash.

Comment: Right, Oracle regexes don't go for escaping in character classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use NOT regexp_like, which is more clear.  But since you mentioned you don't want to use NOT, then I would probably use this (again, more clear imo):

```
select 'Does NOT contain dash or underscore' as val
from dual 
where regexp_instr('ABC123', '[-_]') = 0;
```

I'm sure you'd have about 20 different regexp versions soon ;-)

If you care about special treatment of empty strings(nulls), use a simple nvl:

```
nvl(regexp_instr('', '[-_]'),0) = 0;
```

I mention this because using regexp_like does not allow for this (nvl isn't a relational operator, but in this case we're comparing instr to a number, so we can use nvl on the instr (left hand) part.

But granted this depends on whether you want to say anything about the existence or non-existence of some characters in a null ;-)